# Add object to a state's property which is an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time trying to do a React project. I'm very new with it so I'm just basing it off from different youtube channels and I'm sure you'll find it messy so I apologize.

I'm doing a blog project, and I'd like to make a comments component for every post. I fetched some objects online to use as the posts, but since there's no comments attribute I tried to add it using useEffect. I however can't add to the comments when submitting using useState. I must be using it incorrectly. I'd check the post object in the console, but the comment array is empty.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false)
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

    //fetch
    useEffect( () => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(posts => {
            setIsLoading(false)
            posts = posts.map(post => {
                post.comment = comments;
                return post
            })
            setPosts(posts.slice(0, 1))
        })
    }, [])

    //add comment
    const addComment = (e, {title}, id) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("Comment: ", title)
        console.log("ID of post: ", id)

        const addedComments = posts.map(post => {
            if(post.id === id) {
                setComments(
                    ...comments,
                    {
                        id: uuid.v4,
                        title: {title}
                    }
                )
            }
        })
    }
```

**CommentForm.js**

```
const CommentForm = ({id, addComment}) => {
    const commentItems = <Comments />

    const [commentData, setCommentData] = useState({
        title: "",
    })

    const {title} = commentData

    const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setCommentData({
            ...commentData,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ (e) => addComment(e, commentData, id) }>
                {JSON.stringify(commentData)}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="title">Add comment:</label>
                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="title" 
                    value={title}
                    onChange={ (e) => onChangeHandler(e)}
                    />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                    { commentItems }
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Console output**

```
App.js:64 Comment:  Test comment

App.js:67 ID of post:  1

App.js:26 
[{…}]
0:
userId: 1
id: 1
title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum↵reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam↵nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
comment: Array(0)
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
length: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are destructing the array seems to be incorrect

```js
if (post.id === id) {
      setComments([
        ...comments,
        {
          id: uuid.v4,
          title: { title },
        },
      ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is where you want to set the comment in your `addedComments` function. You didn't call that function anywhere in the parent function (Of course you can just return the map function instead of putting it inside another function). In addition, In order to set a state, it's better to give the same type as the initial value and in this case, you need an array to show, too. You provided an empty array for `setComments` hook, so you need to set the value as an array and spread current comments in it instead of spreading inside an object.

```
const addedComments = posts.map(post => {
        if(post.id === id) {
            setComments([
               ...comments,
               {
                  id: uuid.v4,
                  title: {title}
               }
            ])
        }
    })
```

I'll update the answer if it does not solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

1. The function `addedComments` is never being called.
2. `setComments` needs to take an array of comments.

These alterations to `addComment` should fix your issue.

```
//add comment
    const addComment = (e, {title}, id) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("Comment: ", title)
        console.log("ID of post: ", id)

        posts.forEach(post => {
            if(post.id === id) {
                setComments([
                    ...comments,
                    {
                        id: uuid.v4,
                        title: {title}
                    }
                ])
            }
        })
    }
```